# Mingw-w64 debugging & profiling : incomplete call stack

Tags: debugging, gcc, stack, mingw, symbols

I am using mingw-w64 4.6.3 for compiling under windows.

When debugging code in QtCreator, I have no proper display of the call stack (?? is displayed instead of the caller list). The current function name is properly displayed, and the local variables are also working.
Also, when profiling with Very Sleepy, I cannot get information about the callers in the function statistics.

On the other hand, when compiling with MinGW 32 bit (4.4), everything works well (debugging and profiling).

In both cases, I compile with -g and link with -Wl,-s

Do you have any idea why the call stack is not available when debugging with MinGW-w64?

Thanks,

Etienne

Answer (score 0):

> -s: Remove all symbol table and relocation information from the executable.

Remove -Wl,-s.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html